# Best way convert json string to Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

i have a filter string, what do you think how can i convert laravel query builder? I used some ways but I wasn't sure.

filter: `[["id","=",2],"or",["id","=",3],"and",["name","LIKE", "%John%"]]`

Thank you.

```
if ($request->get('filter')) {
        $filter = json_decode($request->get('filter'));

        if (gettype($filter[0]) === 'string') {
            list($field, $id) = $filter;

            $query->where($field, $id);
        } elseif (gettype($filter[0]) === 'array') {
            foreach ($filter as $value) {

                if (gettype($value) === 'string') {
                    switch ($value) {
                        case 'or':
                            //
                            break;
                        
                        case 'and':
                            //
                            break;
                    }
                } elseif (gettype($value) === 'array') {
                    list($field, $clause, $id) = $value;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I used some ways". Show them please. What's the error or specific problem you encounter.

Comment: how on earth are you end up with this kind of array?

Comment: @KurtFriars i added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$arr = [["id","=",2],"or",["id","=",3],"and",["name","LIKE", "%John%"]];
$query = Model::query(); // build the empty query
if(size($arr) > 0){ // if there is at least 1 element
    $query->where(...$arr[0]); // apply that element
    for($i = 1; $i < size($arr); $i+=2){ // for every other entry, loop through them 2 by 2 and based of the current one, apply orWhere or where
        if($arr[$i] === "or")
            $query->orWhere(...$arr[$i+1]);
        else
            $query->where(...$arr[$i+1]);
    }
}
$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: @PhatyhT. perfect, for any problem, i'm here

Comment: @PhatyhT. there was a problem, `$i = 0` should be `$i = 1`

Comment: @PhatyhT. per fect, btw, instead of `gettype` you can use `is_array` that can be more clear

Comment: hi, i use your way and final code. https://paste.laravel.io/57fff0b2-263b-41b7-8a5b-2aebee67b522 thanks. changed gettype